# Regex with 25 char length, starting with alphabet

Tags: javascript, regex

**My 5 are conditions**

- Trying to write regex for accepting alphanumeric string.
- It cannot start with number.
- Cannot have `_` hence not using `\w`.
- Length should be exactly `25` characters.
- First 5 should be alphabets and next 20 should be numeric.

**here is my regex**

```
var str = "Aasdfds133147852369852147";
var Exp = /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]){25}$/;  //This fails..ERROR
//var Exp = /^([A-Za-z0-9]){25}$/;  This pass ..SUCCESS, but fails my second condition
if(!str.match(Exp)){
alert("ERROR");
}
else {
alert("SUCCESS");
}
```

*Help me tune my code..*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{24}$/
```

what you're looking for?

[regexr link](http://regexr.com/3bti0) (**with** multiline)

*Explanation:*

- `[a-zA-Z]` checks if the first char is alphabetical.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{24}` checks if the next 24 characters are alphanumeric.

Comment: Add a `$` at the end and `^` at the start.

Comment: This fails the "exact length" condition.

Comment: @Tomalak It does not!
it allows one a-zA-Z and 24 a-zA-Z0-9 characters.

Comment: To enable multiline matching, just use `m` flag. `/^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{24})$/gm`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
var exp = /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]{24}$/;
```

**Breakup:**

```
^                # string start
[A-Za-z]         # match an alphabetic char
[A-Za-z0-9]{24}  # match 24 of an alphabetic char or a digit
$                # string end
```

Answer (score 1):

> It cannot start with number.

```
^(?!\d)
```

> Cannot have _ hence not using \w.

```
^(?!\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

> Length should be exactly 25 characters.

```
^(?!\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{25}$
```

Comment: Wow, unexplained downvote. Let me guess... retaliation voting, @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable?

Comment: What? not me...
I have never done that and i hate people who do that and i certainly would never do it myself.
I'm not offended by your comment.

Comment: Then I don't understand it. It doesn't even make sense. o_O

Answer (score 0):

I had a very simple fix

```
 var exp = /^[A-Za-z]{5}[A-Za-z0-9]{20}$/;
```